# How to control if a component exists in a Tk object/window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I would like to know what is the most effecient way to control if a certain component (label, button or entry) exists already on the Tk object/window.

I have searched on the web for a while and the only thing I found is:

`if component.winfo_exists(): # But this doesn't work for me (I am using Python 3.4)`

I have tried also something (stupid, of course label is not a boolean) like this:

`if not self.label: 
    self.label = Label(self, text="Label")`

I have tried to invent also something cleverer like this:

`if not self.label.exists(): 
    self.label = Label(self, text="Label")`

Since I am a noob using tkinter, I am probably missing something.

**EDIT**

This is the whole class:

class Form(Tk):

```
def __init__(self):

    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.label_question = Label().pack(side=LEFT)
    self.text = StringVar()
    self.entry = Entry().pack(side=LEFT)
    self.button = Button(text="Show", command=self.showName).pack(side=LEFT)
    self.label = None # Initializinh to None

def showName(self):
    self.name = self.text.get()
    if not self.label:
        self.label = Label().pack(side=LEFT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your second approach is good enough.

```
self.label = None  # Initialize `self.label` as None somewhere.

...

if not self.label: 
    self.label = Label(self, text="Label")
```

This will work, because before the label creation, `self.label` is evaluated as false when used as predicate (`bool(None) is False`), and will be evaluated as truth value once the label is set.

---

**UPDATE**

Following line is not what you want, because `pack` does not return anything.

```
self.label = Label().pack(side=LEFT) # pack return nothing -> None
```

`self.label` become `None` after the statement.

You should separate the label creation and packing:

```
self.label = Label()
self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: I have tried to inialize the self.label to None in the constructor but when I click the button which calls the function to create the self.label, many labels are created...

Comment: @bad_alloc, Could you show the minimal code that reveal the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A widget is not created until you create it, so consider using this to check if it exists:

```
try:
    self.label
except NameError:
    self.label = Label()
```

Or initialize it previously:

```
self.label = None
# ...
if self.label is None:
    self.label = Label()
```